# How do i find permutation of a word containing a certain word?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

We can assume the word has all unique characters.
For example, ABC's permutations are ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA. How would I find the number of permutations of ABC containing for example, AB? What is its relation to the original word?

Comment: I have undeleted this question. I notice that you deleted this question shortly after receiving an answer. This is very unkind to your answerer and to later visitors of the site.  It also makes it appear as though you are trying to hide something. **Don't do that**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how many times the substring AB appears in the set of all permutations of the string ABC, simply consider AB as a whole (as if it was a single letter). So instead of 3!, it would be 2! = 2 times.

For example, if you have 3 boxes A, B, C and you want to generate all the permutations of the boxes where the box B is immediately after the box A, then you simply drag A and B at the same time, as if they were a single box. That's the reasoning.

Comment: What is the intuition behind this? And what if the original word is longer, like ABCDEF and I need to find permutations containing "AB" and "FD"?

Comment: Exactly the same. You want to treat "AB" or "FD" as if they were a single unit, so you can assume they are a single letter. So its 5! instead of 6!.

Comment: Ah thanks! I'm not quite understanding why this works however. What if our word was ABCDEF, and we want to find permutations containing ABCDEF. This method would not hold then?

Comment: It works: if you treat ABCDEF as if it was a single letter and calculate the permutations, its 1! = 1.

Comment: For ABCDEF, there are 6! total possible permutations. so for finding which permutations contain AB (IE ABCDEF, CDEFAB, CABDEF, etc) its 5!. To confirm, would a 3 letter search be 4! then? like looking for ABC in ABCDEF's permutations?

Comment: Exactly. In the first case you treat AB as a single letter, so its 5!, and in the second case you treat ABC as a single letter, so its 4!. Just think about this as if you were moving the letters with your hand.